# How to use with/within inside a function?

Tags: r

I'm struggling to understand why does this doesn't work.

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=1:10)

foo <- function(obj, col) {
   with(obj, ls())
   with(obj, print(col))
}
foo(df, a)
```

> [1] "a" "b"
>
> Error in print(col) : object 'a' not found

If this does work:

```
with(df, print(a))
```

Comment: It would probably help to have a wider context about what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`with` is handy and improves readability in an interactive context but can hurt your brain in a programming context where you are passing things back and forth to functions and dealing with things in different environments.  In general within R, using symbols rather than names is a sort of "semantic sugar" that is convenient and readable in interactive use but mildly deprecated for programming [e.g. `$`, `subset`]). If you're willing to compromise as far as using a name (`"a"`) rather than a symbol (`a`) then I would suggest falling back to the simpler `obj[[col]]` rather than using `with` here ...

So, as a self-contained answer:

```
foo <- function(object,col) {
   print(names(object))
   print(object[[col]])
}
```

If you wanted to allow for multiple columns (i.e. a character vector)

```
foo <- function(object,col) {
   print(names(object))
   print(object[col])
}
```

**edit**: refraining from  using `subset` with a function, at @hadley's suggestion

(this will print the answer as a data frame, even if a single column is selected, which may not be what you want).

Comment: deleted my answer, so you might want to change the referral. And +1 for the warning.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I'm not really trying to print anything, I just want to be able to pass on the column to other functions. Looking at functions like subset that take columns as variable names, not strings, I thought it would be easy to do the same. I guess I'll stick with passing on strings. :)

Comment: Except using subset inside a function is bad form, because you will get confusing error messages if the columns aren't as you expect - better to use straight subsetting.

Answer (score 4):

Anything that is passed to a function must be an object, a string or a number. There are two problems with this:

1. In this case you're trying to pass "a" as an object, when you should really be passing it like a string.
2. with(obj, ls())) will return to the functions environment (function scoping) and not the screen unless you tell it to print.

What you want is more like:

```
foo <- function(obj, col) {
       print(with(obj, ls()))
       with(obj, print(obj[[col]]))
    }

foo(df, "a")
```

Or if you're only looking for the one column to be printed:

```
foo <- function(obj, col) {
           with(obj, print(obj[[col]]))
        }

foo(df, "a")
```

Comment: But that's not what he wants: he wants df$a to be printed.

Comment: It's unclear what he wants printed. To me it looks like he wants two lines printed. One with the colnames of the obj and another with the contents of the specified column.

Answer (score 1):

In function argument col is evaluated before using in function with (that opposite to interactive use). Here you have two solutions to this problem.

```
foo1 <- function(obj, col) {
          with(obj, print(eval(col)))
        }
foo1(mydf, quote(a))# here you have to remember to quote argument


foo2 <- function(obj, col) {
          col <- as.expression(as.name(substitute(col)))#corrected after DWIN comment
          with(obj, print(eval(col)))
        }
foo2(mydf, a)# this function does all necessary stuff
```

Comment: +1 for answering the question as posed, although I still think that messing with with/eval/etc. in this way is a bad idea ...

Comment: I couldn't get the second one of them to work. Generally when you use `eval`, you need to specify an environment.