# Extracting parts of a dataframe

Tags: r

I need to extract parts of a dataframe, using the values which I have generated previously.  For example, I have the following data:

```
a<-c(1,2,3,4,6,7,10,12,17,20)
df1<-data.frame(a)
```

I then want to **exclude** these values (in "a" in df1) from df2 when they appear in column b:

```
b<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,7,8,9,10,11,11,11,12,13,14,14:20)
c<-c(1:25)
df1<-data.frame(b,c)
```

So, I should be left with a dataframe with rows 5,8,9,11 etc...

Can anyone help me out with the code to remove these values from my dataframe (df1).

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subset()` will be a good friend to you for this sort of thing:

```
subset(df1, !b %in% a)
```

(The sub-expression `b %in% a` tests each element of `b` to determine whether or not it is in `a`, returning a vector of `TRUE`s and `FALSE`es. `!b %in% a` just negates/flips those Boolean values, so that you end up with a logical vector indexing with `TRUE`s the rows of `df1` that you would like to keep (i.e. those that *don't* appear in a).)

Comment: removed my answer in lieu of this.  you can similarly subset with `[ ]`.  `df1[!df1$b %in% a,]`

Comment: @Justin -- OK, but your answer was just as good, and it's actually generally better to use `[` and `[[` than `subset` in programming (e.g. inside of functions, [see here for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060872/how-to-use-with-within-inside-a-function/6061156#6061156)). `subset()` sure is nice for interactive use, though, and certainly felt more human-readable to me when I was new(er) to programming!

Comment: @JoshO'Brian Thanks, but you took the time to write a complete answer.   When I was learning I appreciated the explanation in addition to the answer.

Comment: @Justin: Josh is right. Your answer is just as good, .. although mys guess is that it is a repeat question.

Comment: Thanks - as a matter of interest - how do I include (instead of exclude) the values in "a" in df1?

Comment: @KatieT -- You can just leave off the negation operator (`!`), like this: `subset(df, a %in% b)`