# Passing an entire group of variables as one argument to a function C++

Tags: c++, r, function, dictionary, arguments

I'm trying to simulate a system that requires multiple variables and parameters and requires multiple nested functions. I was wondering if there was a way to pass them as a group so I can just pass one or two arguments without having to itemize each parameter and variable within each function and trying to keep track of the location of them all in an array/vector. With R, one can use `with()` to evaluate a function using a list of named parameters (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37155800/r-with-function-in-python)). Can you do this with a map in C++?

Comment: Have you tried a `struct`?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Do you mean creating a struct of one and passing it through?

Comment: I don't think was an answer.  I think the answer might be "no, I haven't tried a `struct`"?

Comment: A std::map needs its values to be of the same type, so if you've got a heterogeneous set of arguments, you're out of luck. A struct is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a `struct` with the parameters.

The multiple nested functions either need an override taking such a `struct`, or be rewritten to consume it as their argument.

Now you can pass parameters around in a bundle.

If the set of parameters is not uniform, you might be out of luck.  You also might be able to solve it using inheritance and the like.  It will depend a lot on details.

If there is a significant set of parameters that is uniform, making them a `struct` can reduce the number of parameters you pass around.

```
void do_math(int x, int y, int z, int w);
```

vs

```
struct coords {
  int x,y,z,w;
};
void do_math(coords);
```

if we want to keep the original `do_math` around we can:

```
inline void do_math(coords c) { do_math(c.x, c.y, c.z, c.w); }
```

now we can have code that wants to call `do_math` a bunch of times with tweaks;

```
void do_math_over_and_over(coords c, int x_range) {
  for(int i = 0; i < x_range; ++i) {
    coords tmp = c;
    tmp.x += i;
    do_math(tmp)
  }
}
```

Comment: Using this method though, if I want to create multiple parameter groups, I have to create multiple structs, yes?

Comment: @Plinth yes you do