# Automating lm using lapply and list of formulas

Tags: r

I have a couple of formulas in a list:

```
formulas <- list(
  mpg ~ disp,
  mpg ~ I(1 / disp),
  mpg ~ disp + wt,
  mpg ~ I(1 / disp) + wt
)
```

The column names are taken from `mtcars`. I was wondering why in the code below R cannot find the object `mpg`:

```
lapply(formulas, function(f) with(mtcars, lm(formula = f)))      # (1)
```

The error is: `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'mpg' not found`

This however works

```
with(mtcars, lm(mpg ~ disp))`                                    # (2)
```

but when I try to extract any formula from the list:

```
with(mtcars, lm(formulas[[1]]))                                  # (3)
```

R complains with the same error: `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'mpg' not found`. Surprisingly, when I attach `mtcars` to the global environment `attach(mtcars)`, the expression `(3)` works.

I though I misunderstood `with()` but when I run the line

```
with(mtcars, mpg)
```

I get proper result:

```
[1] 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 10.4 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4
```

Comment: This might be relevant : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060872/how-to-use-with-within-inside-a-function

Comment: `lapply(formulas, function(f) with(mtcars, lm(formula = f, data = mtcars)))` might be sufficient

Comment: All you really need is `lapply(formulas, lm, data = mtcars)`

Comment: thanks for comments and the answer. I missed the parameter `data` in `lm`. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to specify the `data` inside the `lm` call

```
lst <- lapply(formulas, function(f) lm(formula = f, data=mtcars))
lst[[1]]
#Call:
#lm(formula = f, data = mtcars)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)         disp  
#   29.59985     -0.04122
```