# multiple linear models in the same data frame

Tags: r, lm

I have a function that takes a data frame, the first column must be Y and the user selects which column will be X. I need to run multiple linear models in the same data.frame (find which lm has the best results for my user).

Using mtcars dataset, what I have for only one linear model:

```
    results_LM <- function(data, var) {
        fm1 <- as.formula(paste(colnames(data)[1], "~", var))
        lm1(fm, data = data)
        return(lm1)
    }

    fit <- results_LM(mtcars, "disp")
```

I would do the same for each linear model I'll test (and store in a final list that I'll use later):

```
    results_LM <- function(data, var) {
        fm1 <- as.formula(paste(colnames(data)[1], "~", var))
        lm1(fm, data = data)

        fm2 <- as.formula(paste(colnames(data)[1], "~", var, "+ I(", var, "^2)"))
        lm2(fm, data = data)

        all_lm <- list("FirstLM" = lm1, "SeconLM" = lm2)

        return(all_lm)
    }
```

And this goes on for fm3, lm3... fm99, lm 99

This would work, but I guess that are a MUCH better way to do this

Any ideas on how to run multiple linear models in the same data frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alreay solved, looking at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41089772/automating-lm-using-lapply-and-list-of-formulas)
I put all my models inside a list like and used lapply to run all of them

```
results_LM <- function(data, var) {
       formulas <- list(as.formula(paste(colnames(data)[1], "~", var),
                        as.formula(paste(colnames(data)[1], "~", var, "+ I(", var, "^2)")))

       models <- lapply(formulas, lm, data = data)

       return(models)
    }
```