# How to use with() within a function in R?

Tags: r, function, with-statement

How to call the function `with()` within a function?

This example seems useless but point out the problem.
While this work fine:

```
dfTest <- data.frame( a = 1:10)
with(dfTest, lapply(dfTest, FUN = function(i){a}))
$a
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Embedded within a function does not:

```
withLapply = function(x, FUN){
   with(x,
        lapply(x, FUN))
}
withLapply(dfTest, FUN = function(i){a})
  Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'a' not found
```

Comment: Did you read this post: [How to use with/within inside a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060872/how-to-use-with-within-inside-a-function) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case the function is defined within the `with` so free variables in it will refer to the `with` but in the second case the function is defined outside the `with` so free variables will refer to objects in the environment where it is defined, not to those of the `with`.   In general, it is best just not to do this in the first place but if you must then this redefines the environment of `FUN` so that it will work.

```
# not recommended but it will make the code work
withLapply = function(x, FUN){
   with(x,
        lapply(x, {environment(FUN) <- environment(); FUN}))
}
withLapply(dfTest, function(i){a})
```

### proto

This also works since proto resets the environment of functions passed to it.  Again it is probably better just to avoid all these complications.

```
library(proto)
withLapply = function(x, FUN){
   with(x,
        lapply(x, proto(FUN = FUN)[["FUN"]]))
}
withLapply(dfTest, function(i){a})
```

Comment: So why do you say it's not recommended? Is the solution I proposed in the EDIT (using `attach` and `detach`) more recommended?

Comment: Using free variables like this is fragile.  Note the subtle problems that it caused in the question. It would be better to pass the data frame to the function rather than rely on free variables.