# Create a call to `mice::with.mids()`

Tags: r, rlang

I am trying to create a call to `mice::with.mids()`, then evaluate it. It appears the call is being created, but then it cannot be evaluated (must be some environment/scoping issue?). I've created a pared down reproducible example below. Any assistance is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

```r
mice_in_tbl_uvregression <- 
  function(data,   # mice data of class mids
           method, # regression method, eg. lm, glm
           formula = "hp ~ mpg", # character formula (needs to be character for other reasons)
           method.args = NULL # named list of other args that will be passed to `method=`
  ) {
    # construct the call
    fun_call <-
      rlang::call2(
        rlang::expr(with),
        data = data,
        expr = rlang::expr((!!method)(formula = !!as.formula(formula), !!!method.args))
      )
    
    # evaluate call
    eval(fun_call)
  }

set.seed(12345)
mice_in_tbl_uvregression(
  data = mice::mice(mtcars, m = 2),
  method = lm
)
#> Error in eval(predvars, data, env): object 'hp' not found
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: aiya! thank you! I was updating the example from the data set I was working with to mtcars, and neglected to update the formula. The error is the same. The code works just fine outside of my functions, but when I construct the call myself i get the error

Comment: Do you really wanted to use `call2` and rlang or this can be done in a simpler way `fun_call <- glue::glue("with(data = {deparse(substitute(data))}, expr = as.formula({formula}))");   
 eval(parse(text = fun_call))`

Comment: Thanks for responses. I don't necessarily need to use `rlang::call2()`, but I do want it to be a call. I am later updating the call, and the call's underlying list structure makes this task simple. If I can't get it to work within the call framework, I could keep passing along the call ingredients and just build it again (with the modification I will make).

Comment: Issue is related to using `with`  inside a function as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060872/how-to-use-with-within-inside-a-function)

Comment: OK! I was not aware! Very useful, and much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could `parse` a string created (to extract the `language` call) before doing the `eval`uation

```
mice_in_tbl_uvregression <- 
  function(data,   # mice data of class mids
           method, # regression method, eg. lm, glm
           formula = "hp ~ mpg", # character formula (needs to be character for other reasons)
           method.args = NULL # named list of other args that will be passed to `method=`
  ) {
    # construct the call
   
    fun_call <- parse(text = glue::glue("with(data = {deparse(substitute(data))}, expr = {deparse(substitute(method))}(as.formula({formula})))"))
    print(fun_call[[1]])
    out <- eval(fun_call)
    out$call$expr[[2]] <- out$call$expr[[2]][[2]]
   out
    
  }
```

-testing

```
set.seed(12345)
out1 <- mice_in_tbl_uvregression(
  data = mice::mice(mtcars, m = 2),
  method = lm
)
```

-output

```
 out1
call :
with.mids(data = mice::mice(mtcars, m = 2), expr = lm(hp ~ mpg))

call1 :
mice::mice(data = mtcars, m = 2)

nmis :
 mpg  cyl disp   hp drat   wt qsec   vs   am gear carb 
   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 

analyses :
[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = as.formula(hp ~ mpg))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          mpg  
     324.08        -8.83  


[[2]]

Call:
lm(formula = as.formula(hp ~ mpg))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          mpg  
     324.08        -8.83
```

Comment: This will work, thank you!! Just needed to add the regression method to the glue fun, `fun_call <- parse(text = glue::glue("with(data = {deparse(substitute(data))}, expr = {deparse(substitute(method))}(as.formula({formula})))"))`

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg thanks, forgot to update that.